# Uploading a file with WININET on delphi

Tags: delphi, http, wininet

I have a delphi wininet app.

The past week I tried to send information to execute a JSON method, this week I'm trying to upload a file to a web server. I am using the same code with a few modifications, but at the moment that the InternetWriteFile procedure executes, the program raises me an exception: "Controlador no válido".

The code is here:

```
    function TFormMain.CargarArchivo(Archivo, Server: string; Username, Password: PChar; blnSSL, iftoken: Boolean): Boolean;
    var
       Url, Header : String;
       pSession, pConnection, pRequest : HINTERNET;
       flags, dwSize, dwFlags : DWORD;
       dwError, Port : Integer;
       Escritos    : Cardinal;
    begin
       Result := false;
       pSession := InternetOpen(nil, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
       if not Assigned(pSession) then
          raise Exception.Create('InternetOpen failed. ' + WinInetErrorMsg(GetLastError));
       try
          Url := Copy(Server,pos('/Servidor',Server),length(Server));
          if blnSSL then
          begin
             Server := Copy(Server,9,pos('/Servidor',Server)-1);
             Port := INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT
          end
          else
          begin
             Server := Copy(Server,8,pos('/Servidor',Server)-1);
             Server := Copy(Server,1,pos(':',Server)-1);
             Port := 8080;
          end;
          pConnection := InternetConnect(pSession, PChar(Server), port, Username, Password, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
          if not Assigned(pConnection) then
             raise Exception.Create('InternetConnect failed. ' + WinInetErrorMsg(GetLastError));
          try
             if blnSSL then
                flags := INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE
             else
                flags := 0;
             pRequest := HTTPOpenRequest(pConnection, 'POST', PChar(Url), nil, nil, nil, flags, 0);
             if not Assigned(pRequest) then
                raise Exception.Create('HttpOpenRequest failed. ' + WinInetErrorMsg(GetLastError));
             try
                // Set buffer size
                dwSize:=SizeOf(dwFlags);
                // Get the current flags
                if (InternetQueryOption(pRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, @dwFlags, dwSize)) then
                begin
                   // Add desired flags
                   dwFlags:=dwFlags or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID or SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID;
                   // Set new flags
                   if not(InternetSetOption(pRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, @dwFlags, dwSize)) then
                   begin
                      // Get error code
                      dwError:=GetLastError;
                      // Failure
                      MessageBox(Application.Handle, PChar(IntToStr(dwError)), PChar(Application.Title), MB_OK or MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                   end;
                end
                else
                begin
                   // Get error code
                   dwError:=GetLastError;
                   // Failure
                   MessageBox(Application.Handle, PChar(IntToStr(dwError)), PChar(Application.Title), MB_OK or MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                end;
                Header := 'Host: ' + Server + ':' + IntToStr(Port) + #13#10 +
                          'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8'#13#10;
                if iftoken then
                begin
                   Header := Header + 'auth_token: '+token+#13#10;
                   Header := Header + 'Csrf-token: no-check'#13#10;
                end;

                if not HttpAddRequestHeaders(pRequest, PChar(Header), Length(Header), HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD) then
                   raise Exception.Create('HttpAddRequestHeaders failed. ' + WinInetErrorMsg(GetLastError));

                Parameters := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
                Parameters.AddFile('archivo', Archivo, '');
                if not HTTPSendRequest(pRequest, nil, 0, Parameters, Parameters.Size) then
                   raise Exception.Create('HTTPSendRequest failed. ' + WinInetErrorMsg(GetLastError));

                try
                   if not InternetWriteFile(Parameters, Parameters, Parameters.Size, Escritos) then
                      raise Exception.Create('InternetWriteFile failed. ' + WinInetErrorMsg(GetLastError));
                   Result := true;
                finally
                   Parameters.Free;
                end;
             finally
                InternetCloseHandle(pRequest);
             end;
          finally
             InternetCloseHandle(pConnection);
          end;
       finally
          InternetCloseHandle(pSession);
       end;
    end;
```

[image: Exception]

I have tried to initialize the file pointer with FTPOpenFile procedure, but it doesn't work because the server is HTTP, not FTP, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot mix Indy and WinInet in the manner that you are trying to mix them.

You are trying to `POST` an Indy `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` object directly from memory.  That will never work. You have to tell `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` to generate its MIME data from your input parameters and then post that data instead.  `TIdHTTTP.Post()` handles that for you, but you are not using `TIdHTTP`, so you have to do it manually.  In this case, you would have to save the generated `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` data to a separate `TMemoryStream` (using the `TStream.CopyFrom()` method) and then you can post that data using WinInet.

Even then, your `POST` would still break, because:

1. you are not including the required `boundary` parameter in your `Content-Type` request header (`TIdMultipartFormDataStream` generates that value dynamically) so the server can parse the MIME parts correctly.
2. you cannot mix `HTTPSendRequest()` and `InternetWriteFile()` together if they are both trying to send body data for the request.  Pick one or the other.

Try something more like this:

```
PostData := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  Parameters := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
  try
    Parameters.AddFile('archivo', Archivo, '');
    PostData.CopyFrom(Parameters, 0);
    Header := 'Host: ' + Server + ':' + IntToStr(Port) + #13#10 +
              'Content-Type: ' + Parameters.RequestContentType + #13#10;
  finally
    Parameters.Free;
  end;    
  if iftoken then
  begin
    Header := Header + 'auth_token: '+token+#13#10;
    Header := Header + 'Csrf-token: no-check'#13#10;
  end;
  if not HttpAddRequestHeaders(pRequest, PChar(Header), Length(Header), HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD) then
    raise Exception.Create('HttpAddRequestHeaders failed. ' + WinInetErrorMsg(GetLastError));
  if not HTTPSendRequest(pRequest, nil, 0, PostData.Memory, PostData.Size) then
    raise Exception.Create('HTTPSendRequest failed. ' + WinInetErrorMsg(GetLastError));
  Result := True;
finally
  PostData.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Again thank you for the help. I'm really newbie in the handling of this component, I'm used to use INDY, therefore my mix of components .